# methods declaration related to serialization in java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I was going through the java documentation of Serialization and found that if we need to explicitly implement the serialization and deserialization we need to implement the following methods:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
 throws IOException

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
 throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;

private void readObjectNoData()
 throws ObjectStreamException;
```

Could someone please let me know who calls these methods as these methods are not there in the Object class as well as Serializable interface (since it is a marker interface).

Comment: The Java Runtime Library does, when you ask it to serialize or deserialize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could someone please let me know who calls these methods as these methods are not there in the Object class as well as Serializable interface

Even if they would be there, they would not be callable from outside in the "normal" way since they are `private` (finally, they could not even be inherited).

As @Andreas (not me :) ) said in the comments, the runtime library calls them through [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). You can find the relevant code in the Java runtime library in the [`jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.java`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/35f286a7dd46/src/java.base/share/classes/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.java) (link might change over time) source file:

```
...
private Method writeObjectMethod;
private Method readObjectMethod;
private Method readObjectNoDataMethod;

...

writeObjectMethod = getPrivateMethod(cl, "writeObject",
                            new Class<?>[] { ObjectOutputStream.class },
                            Void.TYPE);
readObjectMethod = getPrivateMethod(cl, "readObject",
                            new Class<?>[] { ObjectInputStream.class },
                            Void.TYPE);
readObjectNoDataMethod = getPrivateMethod(
                            cl, "readObjectNoData", null, Void.TYPE);
...
```

`getPrivateMethod()` is a utility method which looks up a given method for a `Class` through the reflection API.

If one of those `Method` references is not null, this means that the corresponding class contains that method, and it can be called like

```
...
writeObjectMethod.invoke(obj, new Object[]{ out });
...
```

at a later time.